# Internal error on deployment to google appengine

Tags: google-app-engine

I'm trying to get Vaadin7 app working on Google app-engine. I use app-engine sdk 1.8.5 with eclipse juno.

Deployment seems to work since I get:

```
------------ Deploying frontend ------------

Preparing to deploy:
    Created staging directory at: '/tmp/appcfg4530509922106401908.tmp'
    Scanning for jsp files.
    Scanning files on local disk.
    Initiating update.
    Cloning 4 static files.
    Cloning 8 application files.

Deploying:
    Uploading 0 files.
    Initializing precompilation...
    Deploying new version.

Verifying availability:
    Will check again in 1 seconds.
    Will check again in 2 seconds.
    Will check again in 4 seconds.
    Will check again in 8 seconds.
    Closing update: new version is ready to start serving.

Updating datastore:
    Uploading index definitions.

Deployment completed successfully
```

However at the end of operation there is a pop-up saying:

```
An internal error occurred during: "Deploying <app-name> to Google".
java.lang.NullPointerException
```

Nothing is written to log file and I have no clue what kind of nullpointer is that. Accessing the application from web-browser gives HTTP 500.
Any tips on what can be the reason/possible solution?

Answer (score 2):

Normally, after a successful deployment, the Google App Engine Eclipse plugin launches a browser tab pointing to **your-app-id**.appspot.com. If this fails, you can get a NullPointerException as you have described.

This is what happens to me, at least, with Eclipse 4.3 (Kepler) and app-engine sdk 1.8.6.

In this situation, your backend has indeed been deployed and it is safe to ignore this error. You will have to, however, launch or refresh your browswer tab manually.